# When I am looking to purchase a SSL Certificate is there any difference between SSL and TLS Server Certificates

Tags: azure, ssl, https

I was wanting to use a SSL certficate but now I understand there is something new called TLS. When I look on the web site for goDaddy for example I don't see mention of TLS.

Is this something that I need to specify or is it something only some certicate sellers provide?

Also when I am setting up my server are there different things I need to do if I am using a TLS certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL and TLS are used together and with certificates they mean the same. SSL and TLS are merely the protocols used for the connection. The certificates you are purchasing are X.509 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificates.

By the way, calling TLS 'new' is a bit wrong. TLS 1.0 was finalized in January 1999 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0) and it is recommended to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) on your servers.

You tagged your question with "azure". On Microsoft Azure will take care of most of the technical details if you use web/worker roles or websites to host your site. Just upload the certificate in the management system and Azure will do the rest. You can read all about it at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/